# Look up key from Json Object - Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

In Neo4j , is there a APOC function that i can use to get value a from jsonObject by passing a Key. For example :

My JsonObject is  :
`{ "masterName" : {"name1" : "A1" , "name2" : "A2", "name3": "A3", "name4" : "A4"}}`

and while importing my csv that has "name" field (values : name1, name2, name3, etc) for which I want to lookup above JsonObjet and get respective value to create nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have your json in a field called myJSON, you could

```
WITH ‘name1’ AS key, line
WITH apoc.convert.fromJsonMap(line.myJSON)[key] AS name
```